# Magento 2 - get Qty of used products of Configurable

Tags: magento2, product, php, ajax, qty

I'm trying to take the various quantities of the products associated with the configurable in this way but the code does not work:

```
$simple_collection = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
$simple_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
}
```

Instead for simple products this code works well:

```
echo $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
```

How can I take the quantity for associated products?

One last question, is it possible to take these quantities in ajax for example at the click on the color?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299798/85907

Comment: Thanks man, i read and i created a custom module for this. Another question: But if i want show qty of a associated product of a configurable using Ajax when i click on a color, how can i do?